# JavaScript: Error at document.getElementById() in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am currently facing an error in JavaScript. The code is given below

```
function loader() {
    size = window.innerWidth;
    size = size - 300;
    mainj = document.getElementById('main1');
    mainj.style.left = size.toString() + 'px';
    submainj = document.getElementById('submain1');
    submainj.style.left = size.toString() + 'px';
    size = mainj.style.top + 26;
    document.getElementById('submain1').style.top = size.toString() + 'px';
}
onload = loader();
```

The error comes only in Internet Explorer and the code works perfectly in Firefox. The error shows is in the fifth line, the error being

```
Message: Object required
Line: 34
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/home.php
```

Line 34 is the 5th line given in the code - 'mainj.style.left.....'
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Formatting your code may help people read it.  Also, have you tried debugging to see if `mainj` and `mainj.style` are undefined?

Comment: formatting? i didnt understand

Comment: You have what should be 10-15 lines of code jammed into 6 with no indenting or spacing.  It's hard to read that way.

Comment: @Anand Split every instruction to one line so we can see which instruction causes the error exactly

Comment: i got that, and yea `mainj` seems to be undefined but it shouldn't be so, because a element with id 'main1' exists and this code works perfectly fine without errors in firefox.

Comment: @AnandS -- see my answer below and add an `else` statement to debug in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
size=window.innerWidth-300;
```

Internet Explorer doesn't have a concept of inner width on window, as far as I know. The following code is a decent cross-browser implementation, similar to something you would see in a library. There are corresponding innerHeight and offsetHeight properties if you needed height as well.

```
var size = 0;
if(window.innerWidth) {
    size = window.innerWidth;
} else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth) {
    size = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
} else if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
    size = document.body.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: Yea the IE error console showed me the error was somewhere else , but your code did the work and now the code is working correctly in IE.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have a DOM element with ID=`main1`

If it **does not exist** then your code will return errors.

what you can do is have a conditional:

```
if(mainj  !== undefined) {  //if mainj is a real object
   //do code with mainj
}
```

Also try using local variables in your code (precede variables with the word `var`) so they do not enter the global scope.

Comment: While mainj might be undefined, I think errors may actually be from IE not having an innerWidth property.

Comment: He said the (possibly incorrect) line number, but then described the line that tries to set the "style.left" property.

Comment: I said according to what the IE Error console showed me, but i guess the error was actually where Jordan stated, Thank you all for the answers

Comment: With a function name like loader, he may WANT to enter the global scope.

Comment: @Neal, IE is notorious for giving quirky error line numbers. I wouldn't trust it.